# How to debug a Python module and python code in Visual Studio Code's launch.json

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

My question may seem simple but, I have a module that I launch in a terminal like this:

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=4 --master_port=29300 train.py      
configs/coco_stuff10k/mask2former_beit_adapter_large_512_40k_cocostuff10k_ss.py --launcher pytorch --
deterministic
```

I have this in my launch.json

```
"configurations": [
{ 
"name": "Python: train.py", 
"type": "python", 
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"console": "integratedTerminal", 
"args": ["-m torch.distributed.launch", "--nproc_per_node=4",
"--master_port=29300",    
"configs/coco_stuff10k/mask2former_beit_adapter_large_512_40k_cocostuff10k_ss.py",
"-launcher pytorch", 
"--deterministic"], 
"justMyCode": true
    }
]
```

error
File "/mnt/sdf1/ViT-Adapter/segmentation/.vscode/launch.json", line 2

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Mate, Put out the whole content of the launch.json file, it would be easier to find out the exact syntax error.